# How to use 2.2 features if I target 2.1?

Tags: java, android, versioning, compatibility

I like to use TrafficStats API in my application. Problem is - I target 2.1

It is really an addon to my application and it will function without this feature. What is the way to include this and keep app compatible with 2.1? I know I can start maintaining 2 APK's but It is something I don't want to do, seems to be troublesome. Is there any other way?

Comment: You can find some solutions [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/backward-compatibility.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any other way?

Step #1: Set your project's build target to Android 2.2 (or higher, if you wish)

Step #2: Wrap all calls to Android 2.2-specific features in version guard blocks:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO) {
  // do something only on 2.2
}
```

Step #3: Ensure your `android:minSdkVersion` is as low as you want (e.g., 7 for Android 2.1)

Step #4: Run the occasional lint check to confirm that you are not accidentally using something particular to Android 2.2 outside of a version guard block

Comment: That looks like a way to go. Now that I reference 2.2 I just worry that I may accidently use some 2.2 specific API. Do you think using conditional compilation and switching to 2.1 to test-compile will be a solid way to test this?

Comment: @katit: "I just worry that I may accidently use some 2.2 specific API" -- that's where lint comes in. It will yelp at you if you do this. "Do you think using conditional compilation and switching to 2.1 to test-compile will be a solid way to test this?" -- I'd just use lint. See http://tools.android.com/recent/lintapicheck

Comment: Hah.. I'm using IntelliJ IDEA and noticed nice validations and stuff. Didn't know it is lint. It seems that the only thig I need to do is to run "Analyze code" from my IDE and it will include lint outputs together with it's own checks